# How to clear all static NAT entries with just one command?

Tags: router, nat, cisco-commands

I am using cisco 2901 Router with IOS version 15M. In the configuration of the router I am using lots of static NAT entries. And I need to change these entries when it is requested.

And a possible solution for this situation are the configuration files that I saved to the *flash0:* of the cisco 2901 router. However, by using configuration files, I can't delete existing NAT entries. But on the other hand, I can create a static NAT entry using these configuration files.

Therefore, I am looking for a command that will clear all the static NAT entries. Then I will create static NAT entries using these configuration files.

Notes:

- I tried the following commands to clear the NAT entries, but these all are for dynamic NAT entries. Thus, they did not work.

`clear ip nat translation *
    clear ip nat translation forced
    do clear ip nat translation *
    do clear ip nat translation forced`

- A possible solution (although it takes too much time): First create a configuration file that does not have any static NAT entry:

  `copy running-config flash0:config_0_entry`

Then copy this configuration to the `startup-config` and reboot. (These two command will wipe out all the static entries.)

```
copy flash0:config_0_entry startup-config
reload
```

Then after reboot, load your configuration file into the router:

```
copy flash0:your_config_file running_config
```

I could use this method, but the reboot takes too much time. I cannot wait that long.

Comment: Have you tried removing the NAT inside and outside from the interface and then using the clear ip nat translation * ? This should allow you to clear the static NAT because it is no longer active on an interface and no active connection.

Comment: You seem to mean static NAT entries you have defined in the configuration. You will need to use the `no` form of the configuration commands to remove the configurations after you have cleared the translations. That would be one `no` command for each command you entered.

Comment: If traffic is still live, then clearing the translations will just have them reappear instantly. The only reliable why I've done it is via the console so I can shutdown the outside interface while making changes. (or replace the startup config and reload, but that's much more disruptive.)

Comment: - @SleepyMan I tried it, and I think it is only working with dynamic nat translation.

Comment: - @RonMaupin  Yes, I know, but I have to enter no commands for every entry. I thought that there should be a shortcut.

Comment: @ysnfrk, this is where a small text editor helps a lot. Just copy the configurations, paste it into the text editor, paste a `no ` in front of each line, then copy the whole thing, and paste it back into the configuration. It should take a matter of seconds.

Comment: -@RickyBeam actually if traffic is still live, and if you write "no ip nat ...." it asks you to clear entry or not and if you type  "yes" and entered, router clears the entry.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your config file that has no NAT entries, upload to your router, remove config.text, change the new config file name to config.text, then run a "configure memory" command to load the config.text file into the running config.

Comment: If you don't specifically turn off the NAT with the `no` form of the command, loading or merging a different configuration into the running configuration will not turn off the NAT. Non-default commands in the running configuration remain unless specifically disabled.

Comment: Well shucks.  Thanks, Ron.  I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

To remove old NAT settings on Cisco router you need to

- 1)Clear all old NAT translations 
  router#clear ip nat translation *
- 2)Disable old NAT pool settings 
  router(config)#no ip nat pool public_access 200.100.10.33 netmask 255.255.255.252
- 3)And finally, disable the translation:
  router(config)#no ip nat inside source list 1 pool public_access overload

From this point you can safely configure the new NAT settings.   (in conf mode) , I prefix my (pre-prepared and ready to paste) nat changes with `do clear ip nat translation`, I can clear and change them fast enough to avoid the problem.

Paste into notepad and use replace or some other method to aid in bulk updates.

Answer (score -1):

firstly:
do clear ip nat translation *
then:
add no to each of your nat translations,
for example:
no ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.1 222.0.1.3
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please don't post images as an answer. Use preformatted text instead using `{` and `}`.

Comment: In addition, clearing NAT *sessions* by removing NAT *configuration* seems like a bad idea.